# how struck.pack() is used in creation packets

Tags: python, struct.pack

i encounter this line in a program for creating icmp ping packets in python

```
header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, my_checksum, ID, 1)
```

what does "bbHHh" means here

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `struct` module?

Comment: yes i read it but i didnt actually understood what format string meant until john zwinck showed me the c structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html - it's a format string.  Your particular example means the equivalent of this in C:

```
 struct Foo {
   signed char a;
   signed char b;
   unsigned short c;
   unsigned short d;
   short e;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters

it means that

```
ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST is a signed char -> integer in python
0 the same
my_checksum is unsigned short -> integer in python
ID the same
h is a short -> integer in python
```